# Can't connect to Wifi in 16.04 after booting from Windows 10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 16.04

I just booted and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows Lenovo Y500 laptop and have been unable to connect to Wifi.

My Wifi network shows up, but refuses to connect.

I have tried every terminal command that I could find in these forums for people with similar issues and nothing has worked.

Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Download wpasupplicant & libpcsclite1 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu in your windows 10.

Copy wpasupplicant_2.4-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb and libpcsclite1_1.8.14-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb to your usb driver.

Boot your Ubuntu 16.04 and mount your usb driver.

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb
sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/usb
```

Install previous deb with dpkg -i

```
sudo dpkg -i /media/usb/libpcsclite1_1.8.14-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /media/usb/wpasupplicant_2.4-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

Set up wireless connection according to https://askubuntu.com/a/417498/426130