# Wifi with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless, connection

I try to establish a wifi connection with my router, however, it does not work, no matter what I try.

`iwconfig` gives:

`lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"A1A0"

          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm

          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.`.

I also tried to restart the network manager with `sudo service network-manager stop` and then `sudo service network-manager start`. It did not help either.

I also stopped the network manager and tried:

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid $SSID`and `sudo dhclient -v wlan0`. It did not work that way.

`lshw -C network` gives:
`*-network
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11`, so the driver is from Realtek (*rtl8723be*).

I also tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`. No success.

Has anybody an idea, what I can try to wireless connect to my router?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/how-do-i-get-a-realtek-rtl8723be-wireless-card-to-work You probably only need the ant_sel step.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the security settings correct. Unless you have the WPA2 password set, the wireless will never associate.

[Ubuntu Server - How to connect to wireless WPA2 personal network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271378/ubuntu-server-how-to-connect-to-wireless-wpa2-personal-network) has further instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use Vrtual Machine? I had the same problem when I was using Ubuntu in VMWare Player and when I installed Ubuntu GNU/Linux 16.04 lts as base system, problem solved...